# Bounty from Community

Tags: discussion, support, bounty, community-user

[This question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/332839/checking-universal-closedness-on-immersions) has an outstanding bounty from the Community user.

How does that happen?

Comment: I suspect the bounty was offered by a user (perhaps the OP) whose account since then was deleted.  Thus, the ownership of the bounty went to the Community User.

Comment: Joel is correct. More information here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196716/bounty-awarded-by-community?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thanks, @JoelReyesNoche and ToddTrimble.  No need to keep this question open now.

Comment: I will add that if you look at the [questions revision history](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/332839/revisions) or [at the timeline](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/332839/timeline) you can see there: "Notice added Authoritative reference needed by user140765." (Although I am not sure whether this message is still displayed there after the bounty ends.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: I don't understand what that means.

Comment: @StevenLandsburg I was merely pointing out the fact that the username was shown there. When starting a bounty, you can choose one of several bounty remarks - as you can try for yourself if you try to offer bounty, but do not submit it or you can look at the screenshot shown in this answer: [How should bounties be categorized?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/103956#103981). "Authoritative reference needed" is one of the possible choice for bounty reason.

Comment: @ToddTrimble Perhaps this is closed to the question at hand: [When can the community user offer a bounty?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287611) (The one you linked is about bounty *awarded* by the Community user, this one is about bounty *offered* by the Community user.)

Comment: If I'm correct it was given by the user "*Cut the wood*" before this user complained in this meta post (https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4253/are-the-questions-of-deleted-users-having-no-accepted-answers-to-be-deleted) and then closed this account (which is seemingly one among many others).

Comment: @YCor The bounty was offered by user with id 140765. As far as I can tell from [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=kartop_man+site%3Amathoverflow.net) and [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/revision/1060857/1310319/username-of-a-given-user?num=140765), the username was kartop_man. (Those result will eventually disappear - SEDE after the next update of the data, probably also Google after the crawler looks at a newer version of those pages.) The post you linked shows that "Cut the wood " had userid 141414.

Comment: BTW I see bounties from user with id 140765 on questions 
[331860](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/331860/revisions)
[331917](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/331917/revisions), 
[332839](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/332839/revisions) and 
[330689](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/330689/revisions).

Comment: Also bounties have been cast by two distinct "new" users at questions [333144](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/333144/) and [333039](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/333039/strongly-abnormal-schemes). It's strange that new users with no reputation (no question/answer) can cast such bounties. I don't know if I should post a separate meta question for this sounds as a loophole.

Comment: @YCor: I think these users used up their association bonus for the bounty. Although I find it weird that it is not easy to associate their MO accounts with those at other SE sites: for example, user 333144 has apparently a different username at SE, see https://stackexchange.com/users/6543246/stepan-banach?tab=activity.

Answer (score 7):

This is answered at [the StackExchange bounty FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work).  If a user account is deleted with an outstanding bounty, then the Community user becomes the bounty owner, and the points are eventually awarded following the "no intervention" rules.